# Is there a RxJS equivalent for other design patterns in Javascript/Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm finally trying to learn the design patterns but I was already using RxJS, now that I finally learned about the Observer pattern, I can see how easy they make to implement it.

So I was wondering: is there a RxJS equivalent for other design patterns?

(As in libs that makes it easier to implement those design patterns.)